# Codeigniter Oracle PDO-oci

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, pdo

I am developing an application in Codeigniter. i have Oracle database and large number of data to use in my application. 
i want to connect PDO-oci.

i didn't find any solution. **Please help me to connect *oracle* PDO-OCI to codeigniter.**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:dbname=(DESCRIPTION =
                    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MY HOST NAME)(PORT = 1521))
                    (CONNECT_DATA =
                      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
                    )
                  )',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'MYUSERNAME',
    'password' => 'MYPASSWORD',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```

and the error is

[Screen shot](http://screencast.com/t/mtnVIr1oHH1R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DSN is invalid. As [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php) in the PHP manual the DSN prefix should be `oci:` like so:

```
'dsn'   => 'oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MY HOST NAME)(PORT = 1521))
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
                )
              )',
```

I would, however, recommend using the 'EZCONNECT' syntax as this doesn't clutter your code:

```
'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=hostname/orcl',
```